# compare records in the same table and calculate difference at different dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have one table that contains a list of stocks and their weights for certain dates. What I would like to do is to select the stocks that belong to the portfolio at two different dates and compare the weights. Simple example below,

```
Date 1st March 2015              Date 1st May 2015
Stock Name    Weight             Stock Name    Weight
ABC           20                 MNO           30
DEF           15                 XYZ           25
MNO           40                 LMN           30
LMN           25                 PPP           10
                                 KLM           5
                                 ABC           20
```

Result I would like

```
 Stock Name    Weight Change
 ABC           0
 DEF           -15
 MNO           -10
 LMN           5
 PPP           10
 KLM           5
 XYZ           25
```

This is all I have so far which is not very close to what I need!

```
 with t0 as
(select * from PORT_WGT
and port_name = 'My Port'
and wgt <> 0 
and pricedate = '2015-01-02'),
t1 as
(select * from PORT_WGT
where counterparty = 'JPM'
and port_name = 'My Port'
and wgt <> 0 
and pricedate = '2015-01-30')
select * from t0 union all
select * from t1
```

**update**

Just realised I was using the wrong type of join, please see my updated query. I just need to calculate the change in weights

```
 with t0 as
 (select * from PORT_WGT
 where port_name = 'My Port'
 and wgt <> 0 
 and pricedate = '2015-01-02'),
 t1 as
(select * from PORT_WGT
where port_name = 'My Port'
and wgt <> 0 
and pricedate = '2015-01-30')
select coalesce(t0.sedol, t1.sedol), coalesce(t0.co_name, t1.co_name)  from      t0 full outer join t1 on t0.sedolchk  = t1.sedolchk
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the 2 CTEs:

```
;WITH t0 AS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM PORT_WGT
   WHERE counterparty = 'JPM'
         and port_name = 'My Port'
         and wgt <> 0 
         and pricedate = '2015-01-02'
), t1 as (
   SELECT * 
   FROM PORT_WGT
   WHERE counterparty = 'JPM'
         and port_name = 'My Port'
         and wgt <> 0 
         and pricedate = '2015-01-30')
SELECT COALESCE(t0.[Stock Name], t1.[Stock Name]) AS [Stock Name],
       COALESCE(t1.Weight, 0) - COALESCE(t0.Weight, 0) AS WeightChange
FROM t0 
FULL OUTER JOIN t1 ON t0.[Stock Name] = t1.[Stock Name]
ORDER BY [Stock Name]
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0679/3)

You can alternatively use *conditional aggregates*:

```
select [Stock Name], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN pricedate = '2015-01-30' THEN Weight 
                ELSE 0
           END)
       -
       SUM(CASE WHEN pricedate = '2015-01-02' THEN Weight 
                ELSE 0
           END) AS WeightChange
from PORT_WGT
where counterparty = 'JPM' and port_name = 'My Port' and wgt <> 0 
      and (pricedate = '2015-01-02' OR pricedate = '2015-01-30')
group by [Stock Name]
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0679/1)

Comment: Sorry Giorgos I just realised that the query above does work however every row appears twice. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @mHelpMe Well, with sample data you provided the issue you refer to is not reproducible. You can also check at the edit I made, providing an alternative solution. Can you setup an sqlfiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: your right it does work with my simple example just not with my actual data. Need to think what is causing the rows to be duplicated

Comment: @mHelpMe Most probably something in the `WHERE` conditions of the `CTEs` is causing the problem. Give the second solution a try. It is cleaner I think.